# Angular2 conditional RouterLink for login

Tags: angular

I want the user to be logged if name/password are true, else to stay on the page.
I am using a routerLink but I couldn't figure out how to stop the router from redirecting to the dashboard without checking.
I used a function called test():boolean that returns true if the name/password are valid.

```
<a class="btn rounded-btn" [routerLink]="['dashboard', 'home']" onClick="test()"> Log in </a>
```

here is my login.component :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-login',
    templateUrl: './login.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor() { }
    ngOnInit() { }

    test():boolean{

        return false ;
    }
}
```

Comment: use AuthGuard. Here: http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/12/08/angular-2-redirect-to-previous-url-after-login-with-auth-guard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Router Navigation instead of RouterLink, when username and password will correct it will navigate to dashboard page:

> this.router.navigate(["/dashboard"], {some-data: "otherData"});

You can get more information from the Angular Documentation: https://angular.io/guide/router#navigating-back-to-the-list-component

Comment: where should I declare that router ?

Comment: Inject router into Constructor:
`import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';`

 `constructor(private router: Router) {
       
    }//end of constructor`